# Java Media API: java media api download

Tags: java, media, jmf

Where can i find `javax.media.*` jar file..
In sun site it downloads an installer. Is there any available of the media jar for java?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

There is no `javax.media.*` jar file specifically. That package is in the jmf.jar file. You will need to either run the installer and take out the jar, or the cross platform install is just a zip file (this jar doesn't use any native libraries, so it doesn't need to be installed) that has the jar in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a dependency manager to help keep your libraries organized.  For example, if you have your project setup as a maven project, then you can add any library dependencies to your pom.xml file and it will handle grabbing the resources.

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse with Maven setup (M2Eclipse plugin), then you can search for javax.media and you'll have the option to select from different locations and  specific classes and version numbers that will then stay consistent until you update your dependencies to a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Here u can find all kind of media api and also 3D libraries....

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR

Answer (score 0):

After you download the jmf-2_1_1e-alljava JAR file,  extract the files like you would do any zip folder depending on you operating system.  Open your project in the editor that you use,  right click and select build path,  select libraries,  Select Add JAR/Files,  navigate to where you saved you jmf file, double click the file,  select lib. There you will see what looks like a bunch of jars,  Click on one of them to open it,  It will appear in the large panel before your eyes,  You have to do this for each and every jar,  Did you hear me,  Each and everyone of them, When you're done click OK,  And "Bam",  You should be good to go,  Have fun!..

Answer (score 0):

please go to this link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR

and download Java Media Framework (JMF) 2.1.1e install in your system. after you can find the jar file in location C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib u can see the 
jmf.jar this can be browse by in your project(netbeans) lib right click and add jar file to this slove the issue.