# How to install "javax.media" library in processing 3.3

Tags: processing

I keep on getting the following error in processing 3.3:

The package "javax.media" does not exist. You must be missing a library.

Please suggest a solution for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding ```import javax.media.*;``` at the top ? You should post your code so it's obvious what requires this library ?

Comment: Yes! I did so.

Javax.media is a deprecated library hence the error

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.media` package is not a standard Java package. You can check by looking for it in [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

So you have to track down the jar file that contains the `javax.media` package. Google is your friend here, but here are a couple promising results:

- [Java Media API: java media api download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211632/java-media-api-java-media-api-download)
- [Eclipse missing imports (javax.media.* and com.sun.media.*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163524/eclipse-missing-imports-javax-media-and-com-sun-media)

Once you've found the jar file, you can simply drag it onto your Processing editor to use it in your Processing code.

Comment: I tried that but to no avail.
Processing still shows the same error :|

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you said you tried that? If you find the jar that contains the `javax.media` package and add it to your sketch, your error will go away. If you're still seeing an error, then you haven't added the jar correctly. Can you please be more specific about exactly what you're doing?